# Probability Question : What is more probable, to win with an equally strong opponent, 3 games of 4 or 5 of 8?

Tags: probability

What is more probable, to win with an equally strong opponent, 3 games of 4 or 5 of 8?

My Approach :

$\frac34$ is far from $\frac12$, and $\frac58$ is nearer, so, winning 5 games should be easier, but, using the counting, the answer shows, that probability of winning thrice out of 4 is higher than winning 5 times out of 8.

Comment: Why don't you compute explicitely the two probabilities at stake?

Comment: Is that exactly 3 out of 4; or at least 3 out of 4?

Comment: @Did, I did, that's what I told in the question, that, by counting probability, 3/4 is much likely than 5/8, which doesn't seem right, because, for 3 out of 4, I'm getting probability 7/32, and 8/32 for 5 out of 8.

Comment: @Michael it's exactly 3 out of 4.

Comment: "for 3 out of 4, I'm getting probability 7/32, and 8/32 for 5 out of 8." How did you get these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of winning $k$ games out of $n$ against an equally strong opponent is :

$$ P(k,n) = \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2^n}$$

For $k = 3$, $n = 4$, $ P(k,n) = \frac{4}{16} = \frac14$. For $k = 5$, $n = 8$, $ P(k,n) = \frac{56}{256} < \frac14$.